# VirtualBox slows down when I move the window on a secondary monitor. How can I fix it?

Tags: display, graphics, gpu, virtualbox

**HOST MACHINE**: Macbook Air 2017
**GRAPHICS**: Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB
**MACOS**: Big Sur 11.2.3 and later
**VIRTUAL BOX** Version 6.1.19 and later
**Intel HD Graphics 6000**:
Type: GPU
Bus:  Built-In
VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
Vendor:   Intel
Device ID:    0x1626
Revision ID:  0x0009
Metal Family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily macOS 1

1. On my primary display, every VM runs very well. But as soon as I move the window on the secondary display, every VM becomes very slow and unresponsive sometimes.
2. If I unscale the resolution of the VM, let's say I set 800x600 => the VM becomes responsive even on the secondary monitor.
3. If I close the laptop lid and use the second monitor as the primary display, I can use the VM with no problem even at maximum resolution (in my case is 1920x1080x32 @0.0)
4. I tried different software to emulate VMs and the problem seems to be correlated to VBox only.

**MOST IMPORTANT**
5) If I go to Display settings -> Arrangement and switch the menu bar to the other display, the second display becomes responsive and the primary becomes laggy.

What could be the problem and possible solutions?

I tried to unscale the resolution, use different settings for the VM (different video adapter, memory size, processors...) but with no success.
Furthermore, I also tried to monitor the CPU, GPU, memory usage both on the host and the guest machines and nothing appears to be abnormal.
I tried all the possible VirtualBox version macOS Big Sur compatible and even software to use the iPad as a secondary display and the situation is the same.

Please, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: So, if you don't run VirtualBox, the problem goes away? I think that's the focus of the problem.

Comment: After several test, I can confirm that the problem is strictly related to VBox

Comment: Can you specify the adapter or method used to connect the external display?
For example, on a Macbook Pro running an adapter that supports Displaylink or USB C, it uses software based video to the external display rather than hardware supported, which a thunderbolt one would have.

Comment: I normally use minidisplay port (thunderbolt) to HDMI video adapter. I've tried also thunderbolt to VGA or using the iPad as an external monitor through software -Yam Display in my case- and the results are the same.